# Displaying decimal numbers when button is clicked in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am beginner. I have a UILabel called display. it only displays number . Its a calculator App. now when I click a button with currentTitle "." I want to insert a point to the already existing number on display. Lets Say this is the number "78" now when "." is tapped I want it to be "78." I know how to do this but I don't know how to check if there is already a decimal point in the UILabel so based on that I want to display on screen.

Comment: Maybe you should try regex. Another solution would be to iterate over the given string character by character

Comment: Im newbie I want code for that

Comment: That's not how SO works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check "." present in `YOUR_UILABEL` or not

```
if self.YOUR_UILABEL.text.contains(".") {
    // "." present
} else {
    // "." Not present
}
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Just a short tip:

your textField object conforms to  UITextInputTraits so supposing that you have an a var with the name textField (instance of UITextField)
set this :

```
 textfield.keyboardType = .decimalPad
 textfield.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

this will enforce text direction from right to left like your trying to do (calculator example right ?)

then assign delegate to properly detect punctuation sign:

```
textfield.delegate = self
```

then implement on your view controller :

```
  func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn
        range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        let punctuationSign = textfield.text?.contains(".")

        if punctuationSign == true && string == "." {
            return false
        }
       return true
    }
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything complicated to track your decimal point. Add a Boolean variable to your class/struct or globally, say `decimalPointAdded` and initialise it to false. Now when your decimal point button is tapped check your variable, if it's true you already have added a decimal point, if it is false add the decimal point and set the variable to true.

If you wish to support undoing the last tap then if the removed character is a decimal point set your variable back to false.

HTH